# Reference request: "Schoolbook long multiplication has complextity $O(n^2)$"

Tags: reference-request, computational-complexity

On Wikipedia ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations)), it says that schoolbook long multiplication of an $n$-digit number has complexity $O(n^2)$. Can anyone help to provide a reference for this claim?

Additionally, is this claim dependent on the base in which the number $n$ is expressed, or is it the same for all bases?

Comment: There are some misconceptions. By the definition of schoolbook algorithm, the complexity for multiplying **two** n-digit numbers is $O(n^2)$. If you multiply with a 1-digit number it is $O(n)$, if you multiply with a m-digit number it is $O(nm)$, all measured in single-digit-multiplications. The base of $n$ is irrelevant, it is just a number. If you represent the numbers in another base, the single-digit-multiplications are in that base.

Comment: For a reference, see e.g. Algorithm 1.2. in  R.P. Brent, P. Zimmermann: Modern Computer Arithmetic, Cambridge University Press, 2011. A preliminary version of the book is available from http://maths.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/mca-cup-0.5.9.pdf

Comment: Assuming multiplication and addition of single digit integer literals is $O(1)$, for multiplication of a $m$-digit number with a $n$-digit number where $m\leq n$, we need at most $mn+k+a$ steps where $k$ denotes the number of carries and $a$ is the number of steps to add the $m$-values to get the final result. It is quite evident that $k,a\leq mn$, hence the time complexity is $O(mn)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a reference, it is covered at the start of the first chapter of *Algorithms* by *Dasgupta, Papadimitriou and Vazirani*, but it should be clear that it is true. (I vaguely recall another textbook that also starts with a treatment of arithmetic of natural numbers, but I can't seem to find it, and it's possible that I'm thinking of the book I mentioned above.)

If $a$ and $b$ are $n$-digit numbers, then when we multiply $a$ and $b$ using the school-book method, we multiply each digit of $b$ with each digit of $a$, giving us $n^2$ single-digit multiplications. We then perform $(n-1)$ additions of numbers each with at most $2n$ digits. Since each addition is $O(2n) = O(n)$, the addition part of the process is also $O(n^2)$.

The claim is true regardless of the base that the numbers are written in. Note that $n$ represents the number of digits of the number in the base in which they are written, but actually the claim is true even if $n$ is the number of base-10 digits, and the calculation is performed in some other base.

To see this, note that the number of base-10 digits of a natural number $m$ is
$$
  \left\lfloor \log_{10} (m) \right\rfloor + 1
$$
while the number of base $b$ digits of $m$ is
$$
  \left\lfloor \log_b (m) \right\rfloor + 1.
$$

Since
$$
  \log_b (m) = \frac{\log_{10} (m)}{\log_{10} (b)},
$$
we see that the number of base-$b$ digits of $m$ is at most a constant factor of the number of base-10 digits.